# Did I do this proof right?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $T: R^m-->R^n$ be a linear transformation. Prove that T is injective if and only if for every linearly independent set {$v...v_n$} in $R^m$, the set {$T(v)...T(v_n)$} is also linearly independent in R^n.

1.Take {$v...v_n$} to be a set of linearly independent vectors in $R^n$
2.There must be only unique $T(v)$'s in $R^m$ such that the first set of vectors has only mapping onto $R^m$

Now for the reverse direction.
3.Take a set of transformations {$T(v)...T(v_n)$} in $R^n$.
Then there exist only one vector $R^m$ that maps onto that map onto the transformations in $R^n$

Is this even how this proof goes?

Comment: Not really, I'm afraid.

Comment: For the forward direction, you haven't actually proven the set is linearly independent, just that each $T(v_i)$ is different from the others. That's not a proof of linear independence. For the backward direction, you're assuming $T(v_i)$ are linearly independent and that $v_i$ are linearly independent. So you need to show for any $x,y$ you have that $T(x)=T(y)$ implies $x=y$.

Comment: Hint: If $T$ is linear then it is injective if and only if its kernel is $\{\bf{0}\}$. Why might this be true?

Comment: I didn't check to see which of your two duplicate posts came first, but either way you should not have posted twice. Just edit your first question in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Use the fact that $N(T)=\{0\}$ if and only if $T$ is injective.

Let $m>n$. Let $T$ be injective and $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ be linearly independent. Then set $\sum_1^na_jT(v_j)=0$. Then since $T$ is linear, $T(\sum_1^na_jv_j)=0$. But because $T(0)=0$ and injective, $\sum_1^n a_jv_j=0$ implying that $a_j=0$ for all $j$. Thus, $\{T(v_1),...,T(v_n)\}$ is linearly independent. Now suppose that for $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ linearly independent, $\{T(v_1),...,T(v_n)\}$ is linearly independent. Let $y\in N(T)$. Then $T(y)=0$. Then because $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$ is linearly independent, we may extend this set to a basis $\{v_1,...,v_n,v_{n+1},...,v_m\}$ for $\mathbb{R}^m$. Then for some scalars $b_i$ we have $y=\sum_1^mb_jv_j$. Then $T(y)=\sum_1^mb_jT(v_j)=0$. So by assumption $b_j=0$ for all $j$. Then $y=0$. Then $T$ is injective.